# PHP : get real IP address

Tags: php, ip

I am trying to get my real IP address in PHP, in both case I am in localhost or in a server.
I don't want the IP address of the webserver such as localhost or 127.0.0.1 but the IP address of my machine such as seen in the web (the one displayed by icanhazip.com for example).
The only solution I found is to get the IP displayed by a site such as icanhazip.com. Is there any better solution ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php likes a dog in your house,it couldnt know which city(ip) the house in.So,you must rely on a thirdparty site to identify your ip adress.

Answer (score 1):

I have not got your environment, but you could try:

```
$host = gethostname();
$ip   = gethostbyname($host);
```

In PHP version 5.3 and higher. Let us know what happens, it might not work.

Another way, would be to use another server you own, and ask it what your IP address is.

Or you could do a traceroute (on linux) to a domain and work from there:

```
exec('traceroute example.com 2>&1', $out, $code);
if ($code) die("Error: ".join("\n", $out);
print_r($out);
```

I'm sure there are still other ways.

Comment: Thanks, I tried both solutions but none give me correct ip address.